# Shell multiple logs monitoring and correlation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tail

I have been trying this for days but still struggling.

The objective of the script is to perform real time log monitoring on multiple servers (29 in particular) and correlate login failure records between servers. The servers' log will be compressed at 23:59:59 everyday, and a new log starts from 0 o'clock.

My idea was to use `tail -f | grep "failed password" | tee centralized_log` on every server, activated by a loop through all server names, run on background, and output the login failure records to a centralized log. But it dosn't work. And it creates a lot of daemons which will become zombies as soon as I terminates the script.

I am also considering to do `tail` at some minutes interval. But as the logs grow larger, the processing time will increase. How to set a pointer to where the previous `tail` stopped?

So could you please suggest a better and working way to do multiple logs monitoring and correlation. Additional installations are not encouraged unless totally necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If your logs are going through syslog, and you're using `rsyslogd`, then you can configure the syslog on each machine to forward the specific messages you're interested in to one (or two) centralized log servers, using a property match like:

```
:msg, contains, "failed password"
```

See the [rsyslog documentation](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/) for more details about how to set up reliable syslog forwarding.

Comment: It sounds good, but our organization uses syslog-ng I believe. Does syslog-ng has similar functions?

Comment: @user2404894 Yes. `syslog` and its successors provide this functionality since ages.

Comment: How exactly should I start with it?